# Will applying beer on my hair make it appear shiny and lustrous?

Tags: natural-remedies, hair, beauty

There are numerous beauty sites that [claim that](http://beautyblitz.com/hair/hair-how-tos/beauty-daredevil-will-beer-make-my-hair-shiny) applying beer on my hair will make it shiny and lustrous. Is this true?

Comment: Drinking lots of it will make you think you hair is more shiny and lustrous.

Comment: My money is on it making your hair sticky and smelly

Comment: For what it's worth, I've heard men would style their hair with beer back in the day.